# Regex substitution '$1' - why is it a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Silly question, but I'll ask it anyway: Why is the substitution part of a regular expression in JavaScript encompassed in quotes as a string, where it seems to be a variable in its own right? eg '$2'

```
alert("banana split") // nana split
function reg(afilename)
{
    var rexp = new RegExp(/^(ba)(.+)/gim)
    var newName = afilename.replace(rexp, '$2')
    return newName
}
```

Comment: `$2` is indeed a string that is interpreted by underlying regex engine. JS code doesn't know what `$2` is representing.

Comment: Regular expressions are kinda it's own thing, so it's like calling a program in a different language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's *not* a [Javascript] variable in its own right.

If you didn't single-quote it, JavaScript would try to pass the value of the variable `$2` as an argument (yes, you can give JavaScript variables names starting with `$`), except you don't have one.

This way, the Regex engine gets the actual, literal string `$2`, and gives it its own special meaning.

It's a perfect example of abstraction, where you can witness two "layers" of software interacting. Consider also `document.write('<p>Text</p>');` — you wouldn't want JavaScript to try to parse that HTML, right? You want to pass it verbatim to the entity that is going to handle it.